# Nestjs failed to deploy on cpanel

Tags: node.js, deployment, nestjs, cpanel

I'm trying to deploy my backend application on cpanel and I'm getting an error like this
what should i do to solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

```
> test3@0.0.1 start /home/nandaken/inventory
> nest start
stderr:
npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /home/nandaken/nodevenv/inventory/12/bin/node but npm is using /opt/alt/alt-nodejs12/root/usr/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.
sh: nest: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! test3@0.0.1 start: `nest start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the test3@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/nandaken/.npm/_logs/2023-01-28T08_16_43_494Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `cpanel` is calling the `start`script which is running `nest start`. More than likely, you only have production dependencies installed, so `@nestjs/cli` isn't installed because it is a devDependency. Either configure `cpanel` to call a different start script (like `start:prod` which should map to `node dist/main`) or change your `start` script to run the proper `js` file (like `node dist/main`). The other option would be to install `@nestjs/cli` as a production dependency, but I wouldn't suggest that